# ELKI Kmeans clustering Task failed error for high dimensional data

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, gensim, doc2vec, elki

I have a 60000 documents which i processed in `gensim` and got a 60000*300 matrix. I exported this as a `csv` file. When i import this in `ELKI` environment and run `Kmeans` clustering, i am getting below error.

```
Task failed
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.type.NoSupportedDataTypeException: No data type found satisfying: NumberVector,field AND NumberVector,variable
Available types: DBID DoubleVector,variable,mindim=266,maxdim=300 LabelList
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.AbstractDatabase.getRelation(AbstractDatabase.java:126)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.AbstractAlgorithm.run(AbstractAlgorithm.java:81)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.AlgorithmStep.runAlgorithms(AlgorithmStep.java:105)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:112)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:61)
    at [...]
```

Below is the ELKI settings i have used
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds strange, but i found the solution to this issue by opening the exported `CSV` file and doing `Save As` and saving again as a `CSV` file. While size of the original file is 437MB, the second file is 163MB. I used the numpy function `np.savetxt` for saving the `doc2vec` vector. So it seems to be a `Python` issue instead of being `ELKI` issue.

---

**Edit**: Above solution is not useful. I instead exported the `doc2vec` output which was created using `gensim` library and while exporting format of the values were decided explicitly as `%1.22e`. i.e. the values exported are in exponential format and values have length of 22. Below is the entire line of code.

```
textVect = model.docvecs.doctag_syn0
np.savetxt('D:\Backup\expo22.csv',textVect,delimiter=',',fmt=('%1.22e'))
```

`CSV` file thus created runs without any issue in ELKI environment.

Comment: You need to tell people then what you used. Also, how you generated the file in the first place. Because I doubt that if I "save as" in Notepad.exe, that this will change anything.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, i have added the additional details.

Comment: Thank you. The format string makes more sense. I am surprised that exponential format isn't default with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

The error (which took me a bit to understand, when I saw it the first time) says that your data has the "shape"

```
variable,mindim=266,maxdim=300
```

I.e. some lines have only 266 columns, some have 300. This may be a file format issue, for example due to NaN, missing values, or similar bad characters.

You get that error if you try to run an algorithm like kmeans that assumes the data comes from a R^d vectorspace (that is the `NumberVector,field` requirement), because the input data is not meeting this requirement.

Comment: Thanks you for looking into this. I checked the `numpy` array in Python as well as the exported `CSV` file. However, none of the values are missing and neither any value is NaN. This sounds strange, but i found the solution to this issue by opening the exported `CSV` file and doing `Save As` and saving again as a `CSV` file. While size of the original file is 437MB, the second file is 163MB. I am posting this as solution. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: I think its because of the decimal points. Doing a `Save As` only rounds the decimals.